# Rain World : How to have intelligent movement / animation?

Tags: animation, physics, skeletal-animation

In the project [**RainWorld**](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/rain-world/project-rain-world/posts) the characters seem to move "intelligently" as they move "unrestricted". They seem to know "how" to move their limbs and "what" needs to be done.
Here for an example the lizard seems to know how to move his body after he got struck by a weapon.

[image]

Also here it looks as if it is intelligently grasping the long ladder/using the jet thinging to climb itself up.
[image]

I had been looking into many sources to find out how such gets done but with no significant result. I need help to point myself to the right direction.

Edit

- I have figured out [**from dev log**](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=22849.0)  that characters are just bunch of boxs connected/bounded by an elastic bound "string". But the way the character moves still eludes me.

Comment: It sounds like you have already visited the best possible resource for answering this question, which is the developer's blog.  No one would know better than them.

Comment: @SethBattin But the log is on http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php a website that seems more like a public place for anyone to freely share their progress. I must search by his name and try to sort through all his posts. It looks not like organized or that I cannot find a proper way to search on the forum. And still, I couldn't find a resource on how he got done the animation.

Comment: I would suggest you try and contact the developer :)